# Azure Function built in VS vs built in portal performance for adding in Storage Queue

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage-queues

I noticed that Adding messages to Storage queue was quite slow (average of 1.5s) from an HTTP Azure Fucntion compared to other functions created on Azure Portal.

To test this, I have created a very basic azure function that takes the HTTP request, adds a uniqe ID to it and addds it as a message to Storage Queue. I created 2 similar Function Apps. On one I created this easy azure function on the Azure Portal, and on the 2nd one I uploaded through a new VS project. The performance of the VS project Function was an average of 900ms running time over 500 requests. The performance of the function created on the Azure Portal had an average of 200ms running time over 500 requests. Why is there so much performance difference?

Function below:

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            [Queue("data"), StorageAccount("AzureWebJobsStorage")] ICollector<string> queue,
            ILogger log)
        {
            string uniqId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");

            string queryString = $"{req.QueryString.ToString().Trim('?')}&ui={uniqId}";
            queue.Add(queryString);

            return new OkObjectResult("OK");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a Code Type difference between Portal Azure Functions and VS IDE Azure Functions Project is C# Script (.csx) Type for Portal Function App Extension and C# Class Library (.cs) that shows the reason for performance difference.

As stated in this MS [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp?tabs=functionsv2#how-csx-works) of Azure Functions, it may make a small difference for portal functions as they have to get compiled and then run and Deploying from IDE are precompiled functions. Comparatively, pre-compiled functions will have upper hand.

Comment: This is the opposite of what my tests are showing. The functions created in the Azure portal have an average of 4x more performance when adding a message to the storage queue then VS-created functions.

Comment: Please check the given MS Doc once as Microsoft mentioned the cold start time is more for the C# Script Azure Portal Functions.